# Infragistics IgniteUI Tree Load OnDemand

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am using the plugin http://www.igniteui.com/tree/overview and want to load the tree data on demand.

My declaration of the tree is :

```
$("#tree").igTree({
            checkboxMode: "off",
            singleBranchExpand: true,
            loadOnDemand: true,
            dataSourceUrl : "/home/getagreements",
            nodeClick: function (evt, ui) {
            },
            dataSourceType: "json",
            initialExpandDepth: -1,
            pathSeparator: ".",
            bindings: {
                textKey: "Text",
                valueKey: "Value",
                imageUrlKey: "ImageUrl",
                childDataProperty: "Value",
                Description: "Description"
                },

            },
            dragAndDrop: false,
            nodeExpanding: function (evt, ui) {
            }
        });
```

and the JSON output for home/getagreements is

```
 return Json(agrmnts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

where

```
 List<Agreements> agrmnts = new List<Agreements>();
```

and the class definitions as below:

```
 [JsonObject(MemberSerialization = Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class AgreementNode
    {
        [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
        public string AgreementNbr { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
        public string ExternalDescription { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 4)]
        public string EffDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 5)]
        public string ExpDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 6)]
        public string ReleaseStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 7)]
        public string ImageUrl  { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 8)]
        public string Folder    { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 9)]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(Order = 10)]
        public string Text { get; set; }




    }

    public class Agreements
    {
        public string AgreementType { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Folder { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public List<AgreementNode> agreements { get; set; }

    }
```

The first level data is displayed correct but when I click the node the same data is binding again. Please suggest if I am missing any configuration settings for Loading on Demand[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the current configuration the `igTree` is using the `dataSourceUrl` to request the new data from the same controller action you used to bind the initial level. At this point you would need to use the parameters the tree is providing to the controller action - path, binding and depth - to return the correct layer of data.

[Here's an example of how you can do this.](http://www.igniteui.com/tree/aspnet-mvc-load-on-demand)

Comment: how would load a combo box column in an iggrid on demand? I have an editor window that has a column with a combo box that is not being populated when opened.